# How to set HTTP request timeout with Q-IO

Tags: node.js, promise, q

We're using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) and [Q-IO](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io) to turn HTTP requests into promises. Sometimes our requests time out -- a little too fast for our taste.

Is there a way to set the length of timeout for these "QHTTP" queries?

```js
function promiseAQuery()
{
    var QHttp = require( 'q-io/http' );

    return QHttp.request({
        url    : 'http://www.domain.com/',
        method : 'GET'
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `QHttp.request.setTimeout`?

Comment: Unfortunately `QHttp.request()` returns a Promise. It's not just a simple extension of `http.request` object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `timeout` method on the request, this will cause the promise to be rejected if it doesn't return within the timeout period.

```
return QHttp.request({
    url    : 'http://www.domain.com/',
    method : 'GET'
})
.timeout(5000); //timeout in milliseconds
```